# Apple/Android 3rd Party Merchant Services

Tags: android, iphone, app-store, google-play

I am having a hard time finding any information regarding 3rd party merchant services in an iPhone/Android app stores. I am developing my application on the Flex platform so that I can release it to both major systems. It requires a subscription in order to unlock major features and I would like to include a credit card form that auth's against a 3rd party merchant. Is this legal or will my app be turned away from the respected markets? I know they are looking to skim 30% off the top of all sales... I would prefer to write it once and be done with it, opposed to making it work for each marketplace.

Spark Notes: Will Apple/Android allow the use of a 3rd party merchant checkout in a free app?

**Edit**: 
As CW so *helpfully* noted, I am not seeking legal advice. I need to know if my apps will be rejected (not approved) based upon this purchasing model.

Upon further research it would seem Apple wants every single purchase routed through their pockets. [Section 11](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies) of this document goes into high detail on this issue.

1. Purchasing and currencies

11.1
Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected

11.2
Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected

11.3
Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected

11.12
Apps offering subscriptions must do so using IAP, Apple will share the same 70/30 revenue split with developers for these purchases, as set forth in the Developer Program License Agreement.

11.13
Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, such as a “buy” button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

If anyone knows about Android I would really appreciate it.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. Please consult with qualified legal counsel for legal questions.

Comment: Not a legal question, "legal" pertains to specific market guidelines.

Comment: Assisting you with interpreting those market guidelines is the responsibility of qualified legal counsel, as those "market guidelines" come in the form of terms of service and related agreements.

Comment: Apple cares, Google does not. I use third party payments in my Android app without any repercussions - in-app Google Checkout is an option though.

Comment: Thank you Seva. CW has really not been helpful. I really appreciate your input.

Comment: Also, Seva if you would please post your answer I will mark it.

Comment: Google [cares](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/news/2012/03/new-android-market-rule-prohibits-apps-that-use-third-party-in-app-payment-services.ars) - may not be as quick and strikt as Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the rule with the Play store from personal experience.
If you're selling external products you can use any payment system that you want (For example you're selling a music track, that can be played outside your app).
On the other hand, if you're selling in app products, like a sword if it's a game or premium service, you MUST use google checkout.

http://www.android.com/us/developer-content-policy.html#payments

Check the paid and free section.